# When I convert a map object to list object in Python using list(), and apply list() again to this list, why does the list become empty?

Tags: python, list

Please follow along this code:

```
def addition(n): 
    return n + n

numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4) 
result = map(addition, numbers) 
print(list(result))
```

Output: [2, 4, 6, 8]

Now when I apply list() again on result, which has already become a list, result turns out to be empty.

```
list(result)
```

Output: []

Why is this so?

Comment: Have you tried ```result = list(result)```?

Comment: Printing `list(list(result))` gives the original result, are you perhaps trying `list(print(list(result)))`? The return of `print()` is `None`. But running your code and just adding `print(list(list(result)))` gives the expected result list.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur, now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map object is a generator.

```
list(result)
```

involves iterating through the iterator.  The iterator is now finished.  When you try again, there is no data to return, so you have an empty list.  If you reset the iterator in some way, you can get the expected results.

This is something like reading an entire file, and then wondering why your next `read` loop doesn't return anything: you're at the end.

Comment: To be pedantic, `map` objects are *not* generators, but the are iterators

Comment: Good point ... I chose an inappropriate "simplification".  Not good; fixing ...  You're being **accurate**, not pedantic.  Thanks.